# OpenGL : GL_QUADS hides part of glutBitmapCharacter

Tags: opengl, text, graphics, 3d, geometry

I am trying to visualize a CAD geometry where GL_QUADS is used for the geometry and glutBitmapCharacter to annotate with a text.

The GL_QUADS hides the text partially (e.g 33,32,... here) for some view orientations (picture 1).

[image: Picture 1: Obscured annotation]

If I use glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) to get the text displayed properly, I get the text that is supposed  to annotate the back surface is also displayed (picture 2).

[image: Picture 2: Back surf annotation is shown]

My objective is to annotate the visible front surfaces without being obscured but having the annotation on the back surfaces not shown.

(I am able to solve this by slightly offsetting the annotation normal to the quad, but this will cause me some other issues in my program, so I don't prefer this solution)

Could somebody please suggest me a solution ?

Comment: It's tricky to get this sort of thing working perfectly. Slightly offsetting the text is pretty much the easiest way. You could also turn off depth test as you did, and then do your own tests on the visibility of the faces before drawing the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I expect you already know, it looks like the text is getting cut off because of the way it's positioned/oriented - it is drawing from a point and from right-to-left on the screen.

If you don't want to offset it (as you already mentioned, but I still suggest as it's the simple solution) then one way might be to rotate the text the same way the object's being rotated. This would (I'd expect) simply be a matter of changing where you draw the text to the same place you draw each quad (thus using the same Matrix). Of course then the text won't be as legible. This solution also requires the use of a different Object for rendering the text, such as [FreeType Fonts.](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/)

EDIT 2: another solution would be [texture-mapped text](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/mjk/tips/TexFont/TexFont.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, But glutBitmapCharacter just render the text directly right? would it be possible to rotate it ?

Comment: Sorry, I also made the assumption that the goal was text, not a specific Object type. Such examples might be FreeType Fonts ( http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/  , or,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085832).

Another interesting solution, again, if you are willing to use other ways of rendering text, is to use texture-mapped text. This article looks like it covers some of your very issues:
ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/mjk/tips/TexFont/TexFont.html

Answer (score 0):

> Could somebody please suggest me a solution ?

You need to implement collision detection engine.

If point in 3d space at which label must be displayed is not obscured, render text with depth test disabled. This will fix your problem completely.

As far as I can tell, there's no other way to solve the problem if you want to keep letters oriented towards viewer - no matter what you do, there will always be a a good chance of them being partially obscured by something else.

Since you need a very specific kind of collision detection (detect visibility of a point), you could try to solve this problem using [select buffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glSelectBuffer.xml). On other hand, detecting ray/triangle (see [gluUnProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml)/[gluProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml)) collision isn't too hard to implement, although on complex scenes things will quickly get more complicated and you'll need to implement scene graph and use algorithms similar to octrees.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to use select buffer.